# Eyeball weight paint/armature issue

Tags: armature, bones

I have some bones I made for my eyes, used automatic weights, and it worked great until I joined it with my main armature. Now when I move my eyes, the mesh deforms in odd ways. I checked the weight paint, and the bones that are controlling each eye still shows the eyeball completely red, so it doesn't seem as if the weight paint got messed up.

Here are my eyes, with a few controllers
[image]

I have the right eye bone selected here, as you can see the weight paint is fully on the mesh
[image]

Here I rotated both eyes to the right, you can see the right eyes mesh is deforming, and the left eye is scaling down, and scaling along the x axis making it flat
[image]

Comment: There might be double transformations, perhaps, possibly from having an extra armature modifier. We won't be able to troubleshoot this without your file, which you can share here. https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Is the armature deform modifier set to “bone envelopes” instead of “vertex groups”? Do the eyes have any other vertex groups on them that another bone could be affecting?

Comment: I ended up finding out about preserve volume button, which fixed the left eye from scaling, however the right eye was still deforming. I did notice when I went into edit mode on the right eye, that it was only partially selected, so perhaps it was only affecting certain parts (even though the weight paint showed all red).

there was no extra armature modifier, and it was set to vertex groups as it should be. So i'm not sure why this problem was happening. I ended up just copying my left eye over and its working find. Very odd! Next time try constraints since that was a huge pain.